# How to use strftime for datetime?

Tags: ruby

Here is the date-time input

```
Puts Time.parse("2021-06-26 12:30:35")
```

Expected output:

```
26-06-2021 12:30:35
```

Comment: Like this? `DateTime.parse("2021-06-26 12:30:35").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: No. I want to capture in which format datetime is.

Comment: It seems to me that manuwell's comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957677/print-datetime-format#comment121869278_68957677 correctly solves the question as asked.

Comment: As @manuwell advises (to use [DateTime#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime)), except I suggest you avoid `parse`. Instead, use [DateTime::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime): `DateTime.strptime('2021-06-26 12:30:35', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #=> #<DateTime: 2021-06-26T12:30:35+00:00 ((2459392j,45035s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`. That's because`DateTime.parse('The problem is that "parse" may yield unexpected results') #=> #<DateTime: 2021-05-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459336j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, I think the question should be edited to put quotation marks around the formatting. It seems that the desired output should be the formatting notations themselves in string form.

Comment: I think the real question here is this:  When Ruby parses a string to create a formatted date, is the source data stored anywhere?  In other words, do we know which substrings were recognized as the year, day, month, etc?  This could indeed be useful information.  In the meantime, the only method I can really think of would be to iterate through a handful of user defined formatting options to test and see if they match the original string.

Comment: It appears that, given a string `str` that represents a date and time, you wish to construct the format string to be used with `strptime` to produce a `DateTime` object that corresponds to the date and time given by `str`. Ruby has no method for doing that, probably because there has been no recognized need for such a method.

Comment: @manuwell Your answers where helpful thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is difference using in parsing and strptime DateTime functions. Parsing the date time string can gives same input datetime  as output shown in example 1. Where  strptime is nothing but string previous time it gives datetime inputs as output with timezone shown in example 2 and it  follows some rules like Datetime formats as shown in examples 3, which throws an error.

- Example 1:

```
INPUT  :
DateTime.parse("02-08-2021 15:20:00").strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
OUTPUT :
02-08-2021 15:20:00
```

- Example:2

```
INPUT  :
DateTime.strptime('02-08-2021 15:20:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
OUTPUT :
2021-08-02T12:30:35+00:00
```

- Example 3:

```
INPUT :
DateTime.strptime('02-08-2021 12:30:35', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
OUTPUT:
Date::ERROR
```